# How can I fix TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a slideshow carousel that allows you to select dots to navigate images, and hit arrows to navigate back and forth, but when the site loads the first image is shown and requires you to select the circle corresponding to the image or cycle through all of the images with the arrows for the image to be shown. Does it have anything to do with the TypeError I'm receiving? How can I fix this?

**Javascript Code**

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

I've tried a lot of things so far but I'm not necessarily advanced enough in javascript to understand the issue.

Comment: Indexes start with '0'. So one thing that goes wrong is: 'if (n > slides.length)'. In case you have 5 slides, the last index is '4'.  Your condition will be true if 'n=6' or greater. But the highest index is '4'. Change it to 'if (n >= slides.length)'.

Comment: Ot sure what the actual problem is as your description is a bit vague, but you should at least correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') occurs because one of your `slides[n]` comes in empty. I assume that you have defined `<script>` js incorrectly. Is your script at the very end of the `<body/>`?